# MvvmCross Xamarin Android Hangs on Splash Screen with linking

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross 6.1.2 with Xamarin Android. With linking “sdk and user assemblies”, my apps hangs in the splash screen. Unlike other linking issues, there is no error in the log. No clue how to fix it.

The normal flow of the init process: Setup.InitializeFirstChance -> App.Initialize -> Setup.InitializeLastChance

What I can identify so far is something get wrong in between App.Initialize and Setup.InitializeLastChance. With linking, app can run up to end of App.Initialize but never reach Setup.InitializeLastChance.

I have attached 2 logs below. Both logs recorded from the end of App.Initialize. The first one is with linking till app hang. The second one is no linking till beginning of Setup.InitializeLastChange.

Log with linking

```
09-12 15:23:40.260 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 7685): [Verbose] Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #12
09-12 15:23:40.292 D/Mono( 7685) : Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> Acr.UserDialogs[0xd727a9c0]: 3
09-12 15:23:40.294 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref Acr.UserDialogs[0xd727a9c0] -> mscorlib[0xd727a180]: 73
09-12 15:23:40.295 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> System.Core[0xc61b91e0]: 8
09-12 15:23:40.295 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> Splat[0xd727bd40]: 2
09-12 15:23:40.295 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref Splat[0xd727bd40] -> mscorlib[0xd727a180]: 74
09-12 15:23:40.298 D/Mono( 7685) : Image addref System.Xml[0xddd06500] -> System.Xml.dll[0xc1166000]: 2
09-12 15:23:40.299 D/Mono( 7685) : Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Xml' (System.Xml.dll)
09-12 15:23:40.299 D/Mono( 7685) : Assembly System.Xml[0xddd06500] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count= 1
09-12 15:23:40.300 D/Mono    ( 7685): AOT: image 'System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:23:40.300 D/Mono( 7685) : AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:23:40.301 D/Mono( 7685) : Config attempting to parse: 'System.Xml.dll.config'.
09-12 15:23:40.301 D/Mono( 7685) : Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Xml/System.Xml.config'.
09-12 15:23:40.301 D/Mono( 7685) : Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> System.Xml[0xddd06500]: 2Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll[External]

09-12 15:23:40.301 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0xddd06500] -> mscorlib[0xd727a180]: 75
09-12 15:23:40.302 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> Plugin.Permissions[0xd727b980]: 2
09-12 15:23:40.302 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.Permissions[0xd727b980] -> mscorlib[0xd727a180]: 76
09-12 15:23:40.302 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions[0xd727b620]: 3
09-12 15:23:40.302 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions[0xd727b620] -> mscorlib[0xd727a180]: 77
09-12 15:23:40.304 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> MvvmCross.Plugin.Network[0xd727b440]: 2Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll[External]
09-12 15:23:40.308 D/Mono    ( 7685): Image addref System.Net.Http[0xddd06680] -> System.Net.Http.dll[0xc1168300]: 2

09-12 15:23:40.308 D/Mono( 7685) : Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Net.Http' (System.Net.Http.dll)
09-12 15:23:40.308 D/Mono( 7685) : Assembly System.Net.Http[0xddd06680] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count= 1
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono    ( 7685): AOT: image 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono( 7685) : AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono( 7685) : Config attempting to parse: 'System.Net.Http.dll.config'.
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono( 7685) : Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.config'.
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono( 7685) : Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> System.Net.Http[0xddd06680]: 2
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xddd06680] -> mscorlib[0xd727a180]: 78
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xd727b560] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0xd727b740]: 3
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0xd727b740] -> System.Core[0xc61b91e0]: 9
09-12 15:23:40.310 D/Mono    ( 7685): Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0xd727b740] -> System[0xc61bbd00]: 12
09-12 15:23:40.345 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 7685): [Verbose] Setup: ViewsContainer start
09-12 15:23:40.348 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 7685): [Verbose] Setup: Views start
```

Log without linking

```
09-12 15:33:28.200 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: ViewModelTypeFinder start
09-12 15:33:28.210 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xe8a8d920] -> Acr.UserDialogs[0xe8a8cd20]: 3
09-12 15:33:28.214 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref Acr.UserDialogs[0xe8a8cd20] -> mscorlib[0xe8a8c480]: 70
09-12 15:33:28.215 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xddd05840] -> System.Core[0xc60af900]: 8
09-12 15:33:28.216 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xe8a8d920] -> Splat[0xe8a8e280]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.216 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref Splat[0xe8a8e280] -> mscorlib[0xe8a8c480]: 71
09-12 15:33:28.220 D/Mono( 8211) : Image addref System.Xml[0xddd065c0] -> System.Xml.dll[0xc1c03f00]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.220 D/Mono( 8211) : Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Xml' (System.Xml.dll)
09-12 15:33:28.220 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly System.Xml[0xddd065c0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count= 1
09-12 15:33:28.222 D/Mono    ( 8211): AOT: image 'System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:33:28.222 D/Mono( 8211) : AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Xml.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Xml.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:33:28.223 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: 'System.Xml.dll.config'.Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll[External]

09-12 15:33:28.223 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Xml/System.Xml.config'.
09-12 15:33:28.223 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xddd05840] -> System.Xml[0xddd065c0]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.223 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref System.Xml[0xddd065c0] -> mscorlib[0xe8a8c480]: 72
09-12 15:33:28.224 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xe8a8d920] -> Plugin.Permissions[0xe8a8dd40]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.224 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.Permissions[0xe8a8dd40] -> mscorlib[0xe8a8c480]: 73
09-12 15:33:28.224 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xe8a8d920] -> Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions[0xe8a8d9e0]: 3
09-12 15:33:28.227 D/Mono    ( 8211): Unloading image System.Runtime.dll[0xc1c04400].Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll[External]

09-12 15:33:28.228 D/Mono( 8211) : Image addref System.Runtime[0xddd05a20] -> System.Runtime.dll[0xc60ec000]: 11
09-12 15:33:28.228 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.dll.config'.
09-12 15:33:28.228 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.config'.
09-12 15:33:28.228 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref Plugin.InAppBilling.Abstractions[0xe8a8d9e0] -> System.Runtime[0xc60af660]: 9
09-12 15:33:28.229 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xe8a8d920] -> MvvmCross.Plugin.Network[0xe8a8d800]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.232 D/Mono    ( 8211): Image addref System.Net.Http[0xddd05a20] -> System.Net.Http.dll[0xc1c05d00]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.232 D/Mono( 8211) : Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Net.Http' (System.Net.Http.dll)
09-12 15:33:28.232 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly System.Net.Http[0xddd05a20] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count= 1
09-12 15:33:28.233 D/Mono    ( 8211): AOT: image 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:33:28.234 D/Mono( 8211) : AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:33:28.234 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: 'System.Net.Http.dll.config'.
09-12 15:33:28.234 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.config'.
09-12 15:33:28.234 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0xddd05840] -> System.Net.Http[0xddd05a20]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.234 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xddd05a20] -> mscorlib[0xe8a8c480]: 74
09-12 15:33:28.234 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref a.Core[0xe8a8d920] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0xe8a8db00]: 3
09-12 15:33:28.256 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: ViewsContainer start
09-12 15:33:28.259 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: Views start
09-12 15:33:28.289 D/Mono( 8211) : Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xddd05cc0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0xc1c06700]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[External]09-12 15:33:28.289 D/Mono( 8211) : Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)

09-12 15:33:28.289 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0xddd05cc0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count= 1
09-12 15:33:28.290 D/Mono    ( 8211): AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:33:28.291 D/Mono( 8211) : AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/a.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
09-12 15:33:28.291 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
09-12 15:33:28.291 D/Mono( 8211) : Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
09-12 15:33:28.291 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xc60af600] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xddd05cc0]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.291 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xddd05cc0] -> mscorlib[0xe8a8c480]: 75
09-12 15:33:28.395 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
09-12 15:33:28.396 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: NavigationSerializer start
09-12 15:33:28.398 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: InpcInterception start
09-12 15:33:28.399 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: InpcInterception start
09-12 15:33:28.402 V/MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup( 8211): [Verbose] Setup: LastChance start
09-12 15:33:28.433 D/Mono( 8211) : Assembly Ref addref a.Droid[0xe8a8c600] -> Plugin.LocalNotifications[0xe8a8dce0]: 2
09-12 15:33:28.433 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.LocalNotifications[0xe8a8dce0] -> mscorlib[0xe8a8c480]: 76
09-12 15:33:28.433 D/Mono    ( 8211): Assembly Ref addref Plugin.LocalNotifications[0xe8a8dce0] -> Plugin.LocalNotifications.Abstractions[0xe8a8dc80]: 2
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Do you have LinkerPleaseInclude file or something that hints which MvvmCross parts not to touch on linking?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have the standard LinkerPleaseInclude for Mvx with a number of changes for my own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of situations are very annoying and very hard to diagnose...

First off, I would suggest using [`linker.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker). You will get much more control over what **shouldn't be linked away** with it - it's very easy to set up as well.

Once you have the `linker.config` file in place, I would suggest trying the setup that I use for one of my apps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linker>   
    <assembly fullname="MvvmCross">
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.IoC.MvxPropertyInjector"/>
        <namespace fullname="MvvmCross.ViewModels" />
    </assembly>
    <assembly fullname="MvvmCross.Forms">
        <type fullname="MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxFormsAppCompatActivity"/>
    </assembly>
    <assembly fullname="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat">
        <type fullname="MvxAppCompatActivity"/>
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

I've got more assemblies listed in my `linker.config` file, but I'm not sure how relevant these would be in your case. Please try adding the above to your `linker.config` file and check if you're still experiencing issues.

If your app still keeps on dying, then what I tend to do is, to literally list all of your assemblies (project references) in the linker file, like so:

```
<assembly fullname="<Assembly_Name>">
    <type fullname="*"/>
</assembly>
<assembly fullname="<Assembly_2_Name>">
    <type fullname="*"/>
</assembly>
```

I do this, because even though you might think that it's `MvvmCross` stuff that's causing problems, chances are that it can be completely different library/assembly. This list, of all of the assemblies, will basically instruct the linker to **keep every `Type`** in these assemblies (won't strip a thing!). The app should run just fine with these. Once it does, you start removing assemblies from the list. You can do it one by one or split it in half and remove first or second half - basically start eliminating assemblies. When you do that, you might want to delete `bin` and `obj`, with each and every assembly elimination - just to be extra sure that dll's are being re-generated.

Comment: You nailed it. It is the Ioc. After included it, initialization is smooth. Thank you very much.